# How to know if the mth root of n is an integer?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, radicals

If n can be represented in binary as a x bit integer, is there any algorithm such that we can determine if the mth root of n is an integer in time polynomial of x ?

Comment: Yes, see, for example, http://cr.yp.to/papers/powers.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

Daniel J. Bernstein, [Detecting perfect powers in essentially linear time](http://cr.yp.to/papers/powers.pdf)